# Message Online Friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

FQL Query

```
 SELECT name, online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid in(SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1= me())
```

By This Query I am getting friends

Please Anyone Tell Me how can I message these online friends.

Comment: Hi, i think your FQL Query should be "SELECT name, online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid in(SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1= me())"

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Assume:

- Your app id is "87741124305"
- "4" is one of your friend uid get from FQL query:

> SELECT uid, name, online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN
>   ('active', 'idle') AND uid in(SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1=
>   me())

- you want to share a link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VM56POaEEX4"
- https://www.youtube.com/facebook_redirect is your app CANVAS_URL

The full link would be:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=87741124305&to=4&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVM56POaEEX4%26feature%3Dshare&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Ffacebook_redirect

[image]

**Method 2:**

Send email to him.The email address is in the form **USERNAME@facebook.com** You can get the USERNAME via FQL query:

> SELECT uid, username, online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence
>   IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid in(SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1=
>   me())

Please note that, some user doesn't have username. Also, you can't send empty body message.

**Method 3:**
You may refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ for Jabber/XMPP service.